# Optimization on subsets of a compact space.

Tags: optimization, compactness

Let $K$ be a compact set and let $f:K \to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Let $B$ be another compact set. Suppose we define,
\begin{align}
a &= \max_{x\in K} f(x) \\
b &= \max_{x\in B\cap K} f(x) \\
c &= \sup_{x\in K \setminus B} f(x).
\end{align}
Then is it obvious that $a = \max\left\{b,c\right\}$?

Comment: Well, it is true, since $K = \{K \cap B \} \cup \{K \setminus B\}$.  If you want you can first argue that $a \geq \max[b,c]$ and then $a \leq \max[b,c]$.

Comment: @Michael Is that really all the justification that is required? I guess I am surprised that one can argue this using only a basic set theoretic relationship without even touching on the supremum / maximum.

Comment: The argument that $a \leq \max[b,c]$ seems to require the most work, a simple argument uses properties of maximizers of continuous functions over compact sets to note there is an $x^* \in K$ such that $a=f(x^*)$. So then $x^*$ must be in either $K \cap B$ or $K \setminus B$.

Comment: If you establish that $x^*$ is in either $K\cap B$ or $K\setminus B$, doesn't that immediately establish *equality* rather than inequality?

Comment: A standard way to prove $x=y$ is to first prove $x\geq y$, then prove $x \leq y$.  I recommend you formally prove that $a\geq \max[b,c]$ and then prove $a\leq \max[b,c]$.  You might leave your answer below.